# Name of Irish-like Christmas song?

Tags: identify-this-song, folk

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrVU_C6Tq9k) video to get some ideas on what to play on an informal Christmas concert. From 0:21 to 0:56 the boy plays a song that sounds quite good. It looks like and Irish song , but I don't know the name.  Does anybody know its name?

Comment: For future questions, here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the old English carol "[God Rest Ye Merry Gentlemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Rest_You_Merry,_Gentlemen)," one of my own personal favorites.  This is a bluegrass version.  It more commonly sounds faintly medieval, probably because of being written in the Aeolian mode (natural minor), where the seventh is a whole-step below the octave, rather than the more modern half-step.

The same mode is often found in [Irish folk music](http://irishguitarpod.com/contentmodes-irish-music/).